# SparkR 2.x application using MongoDB and RStudio

Tags: r, mongodb, apache-spark, rstudio, sparkr

I am trying to workout a Apache Spark application that should run aggregate queries on a MongoDB database and write back the result. I was able to workout Java version of the problem but now need to port same to R language using RStudio.

The Java Version that **WORKED**:-

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(true)
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setSparkHome(SPARK_HOME)
        .setAppName("SparklingMongoApp")
        .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
        .set("spark.app.id", APP)
        .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://admin:password@host:27017/input_collection")
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://admin:password@host:27017/output_collection");


JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaMongoRDD<Document> javaMongoRDD = MongoSpark.load(javaSparkContext);

Dataset<Row> dataset = javaMongoRDD.toDF();

dataset.createOrReplaceTempView(TEMP_VIEW);

// a valid spark sql QUERY
Dataset<Row> computedDataSet = dataset.sqlContext().sql(QUERY);
MongoSpark.save(computedDataSet);
javaSparkContext.close();
```

}

Equivalent R/RStudio version that I am trying to workout:-

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

##PROBLEM - Is this correct way of setting configuration?
sparkConfig <- list("spark.driver.memory"="1g","spark.mongodb.input.uri"="mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/price_subset?authSource=admin","spark.mongodb.output.uri"="mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/price_subset_output?authSource=admin")

customSparkPackages <- c("org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark1-connector_2.11:1.0.0");

##Starting Up: SparkSession
##PROBLEM-1 Is this correct way of initializing spark session ?
sparkSession <- sparkR.session(appName="MongoSparkConnectorTour",master = "local[*]",enableHiveSupport = FALSE,sparkConfig = sparkConfig,sparkPackages = customSparkPackages)


##PROBLEM-2 - This complains about being deprecated. How to fix this ?
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sparkSession)

## Save some data
charactersRdf <- data.frame(list(name=c("Bilbo Baggins", "Gandalf", "Thorin", "Balin", "Kili", "Dwalin", "Oin", "Gloin", "Fili", "Bombur"),
                                 age=c(50, 1000, 195, 178, 77, 169, 167, 158, 82, NA)))

charactersSparkdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, charactersRdf)
#PROBLEM-3 This throws an error - Error in invokeJava(isStatic = FALSE, objId$id, methodName, ...) : 
#  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ConnectionString
write.df(charactersSparkdf, "", source = "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource", mode = "overwrite")
```

I tried following [SparkR](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#starting-up-from-rstudio) docs but still not able to workout a running example.

**Expectations:-**

1. What is correct way of initializing spark session in RStudio. The [MongoDB official sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/sparkR/) doesn't work for me as its for SparkShell only (which get hangs on my machine) and deprecated. I want code snippet that I can run in RStudio.
2. How to fix the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Any sample/reference for working piece of SparkR 2.x + MongoDB 3.x code will be highly appreciated.

Versions:-
Apache Spark - 2.0.1
Java  - 1.8
MongoDB - 3
R - latest

Comment: If you're working with RStudio, you might also give their SparklyR package a try (it has integration with the IDE in RStudio's preview release). http://spark.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it working. Turns out that MongoDB docs has example for Spark 1.6 and I was running Spark 2.0.1.

Anyways, this is what worked for me using RStudio:-

```
 ## Make sure you have SPARK_HOME environment variable set to your spark home director.
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

spark <- sparkR.session(master="local[*]", appName = "mongoSparkR",enableHiveSupport = FALSE,sparkPackages = c("org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0-rc0"),sparkConfig = list(spark.mongodb.input.uri="mongodb://username:password@hostname:27017/database.collection_name?authSource=admin",spark.mongodb.output.uri="mongodb://username:password@hostname:27017/database.collection_name_output?authSource=admin"))

pricing_df <- read.df(source = "com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource",x=10000)
head(pricing_df)
createOrReplaceTempView(pricing_df,"T_YOUR_TABLE")

 ## Obviously this is just a dummy SQL, replace with it yours.
result_df <- sql("SELECT year(price) as YEAR, month(price) as MONTH , SUM(midPrice) as SUM_PRICING_DATA FROM T_YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY year(price),month(price)  ORDER BY year(price),month(price)")


 ## stop instance when done.
sparkR.stop()
```

Make sure you have dependent jars in your `SPARK_HOME/jars` folder.

Extra jars (versions might evolve over time ) that I placed to get this working  :-

```
org.mongodb.spark_mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.0.0-rc0.jar

org.mongodb_mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar
```